# Hover animation reverts to beginning after animation is finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, hover, gradient

Example here:

https://codepen.io/rfehre/pen/mKryEV

CSS

```
.intro-side3.out {
  animation-name: out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

.intro-side3.over {
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
    0%{background-position:100% 49%}
    100%{background-position:0% 52%}
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
    0%{background-position:0% 52%}
    100%{background-position:100% 49%}
}
```

Javascript

```
$('.intro-side3').hover(
function() {
  $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
},
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
  }
);
```

I'm trying to do a gradient animation on a hover, and then to reverse that animation when you mouse off. It's not perfect, but for the most part it's working alright. Except that, if you hover for more than the currently assigned 2 seconds, the gradient reverts back to its initial state. I'm not sure why.

I'm probably missing something obvious, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `animation-fill-mode: forwards;` property

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BVLyvm

You can achieve the same without javascript

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:300);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:800);
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:600);

.bold-600 {
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.main {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.main2 {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.intro-side3 {
  padding: 2rem;
  height: 400px;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: white;
  font-family: montserrat;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #662d91, #00aeef, #ec008c);
  background-size: 600% 600%;
  animation-name: out;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

.intro-side3:hover {
  animation-name: in;
  animation-duration: 2s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes out {
  0% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes in {
  0% {
    background-position: 0% 52%
  }
  100% {
    background-position: 100% 49%
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main2 col-lg-3 col-md-4">
  <h1 style="font-family:montserrat; font-size:24px; padding:20px;">Hover /w Reverse</h2>
    <div class="intro-side3 gradientbg">
      <div class="inner">
        <p>We are here to <span class="bold-600"> do things</span> and <span class="bold-600">also maybe some stuff.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following property to the CSS

animation-iteration-count: 1;